# Pytorch Geometric: How to create a small temporary dataset in a colab notebook from a list of pytorch geometric data objects

Tags: pytorch, dataset, pytorch-geometric

I am working in a Colab sheet and have generated a python list of Pytorch Geometric data objects.  I now want to turn them into a dataset for use just in this notebook.  How can I do this?  The existing documentation seems geared towards long-term datasets.

When I worked on standard Pytorch I used a combination of torch.FloatTensor() and TensorDataset() to create my own dataset for use with random split.